# Why am I getting a ChromeProxyService error with Flutter Web and Chrome

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, flutter-web, flutter-http, flutter-web-browser

I'm using `Flutter` version `3.3.8` and `Google Chrome` version `107.0.5304.110`.

I send an http request, and this is the error that I get:

`ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'xhr': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 30..`

Answer (score 0):

The route to which you send the request may be of type post and you send the request with get or vice versa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).